# PHP particular regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to target only digits that follows non-numeric characters in a string to add some html tags around them.
For the moment i am able to do it on every digit like this :

```
$string = preg_replace('/(\d+)/','<sub>\1</sub>', $string );
```

How can i do to just target digits that follows non-numeric characters ?
The goal is to format strings containing chemical formulas but not the text around it.

Actually `20% O2 in N2` becomes `<sub>2</sub><sub>0</sub>% O<sub>2</sub> in N<sub>2</sub>`

I would like it to be `20% O<sub>2</sub> in N<sub>2</sub>` instead.

How can i do this? Is it possible?

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Try [`preg_replace('/\B\d+|\d+\B/','<span>$0</span>', $string )`](https://regex101.com/r/HTbfOX/1)

Comment: Another idea: `'/\b\d+\b(*SKIP)(*F)|(\d+)/'` that can be used in your code as is.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your first one won't fail properly on double-or-more digit numbers.

Comment: @SebastianProske: I know it won't work in many situations. OP requirements are not that clear since a space is also a non-numeric char.

Comment: Ok sorry i'll edit my question to be more specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can i do to just target digits that follows *non-numeric characters* ?

For digits that follow letters try with a [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?<=[A-Za-z])\d+
```

[See demo at regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/4fsfeM/3) (and replace with `<sub>\0</sub>`)

For [unicode](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) letters use [`\pL` instead of `[A-Za-z]`](https://www.regex101.com/r/4fsfeM/4) together with `u` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

Comment: You're welcome @Kamzz! [Here a PHP demo at eval.in](https://eval.in/736915)

Comment: So, the question was about how to change the digits *after an ASCII letter*. `'~[A-Za-z]\K\d+~'` will also work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have never seen that `\K` before, could you please provide a reference (if possible in `www.regular-expressions.info`)?

Comment: @WalterTross: See SO [regex documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/regex/1338/match-reset-k#t=201702141404196930592). Also, see the *Resetting the match start* section at [pcre.org](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt).

Comment: @WalterTross There's also a nice chapter on [rexegg about `\K`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#K) if you're interested. On [regular-expressions.info you can read here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html).